# Unable to read text files on Windows machine with Pyspark. (Analysis Exception) with a file:// prefix for my file name

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

Error:

> AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/D:/sk -
> Add/Main/2020/Main_2012-01.txt;

Code1 with error:

```
for i in os.listdir():
   if j.endswith('.txt'):
        print(i)
        df= spark.read.text(i)
```

Code2 with same err:

```
path=r"D:\sk - Add\Main\2020"
for i in os.listdir():
   if j.endswith('.txt'):
        print(i)
        df= spark.read.text(path+'\\'+i)
```

Code3 without error:

```
df1=spark.read.text(r'D:\sk - Add\Main\2020\Main_2020-12.txt')
```

Why is it adding `file:/` prefix for my file name and causing the error.
In the 3rd case, it doesn't. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try:  ```spark.textFile("file:///path to the file/")```.

Answer (score 0):

In Code2, can you try as below?

```py
spark.read.text(rf”{path}\{i}”)
```

Explanation:

- `f` is for Python f-strings
- `r` is for Raw string (no formatting is needed)

So you are effectively constructing code3 version